# Send a table in email

Tags: c#, .net, email, data-binding, html-email

I have a requirement to send the results of a query in emails. I am using two methods:

**GetDataTable()** : to execute the query and obtain datatable(which needs to be sent in email)

**SendAutomatedEmail()** : to send automated emails.

Problem: i need to send data table or html table in email, something like code below. this works fine for a string in place of dataTable

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable datatable = GetDataTable();
    SendAutomatedEmail(datatable );
}

    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string CommandText)
    {
        string cnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection2"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cnString);

        string CommandText = "select * from dbo.fs010100 (nolock)";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand =  new SqlCommand( CommandText, sqlConnection);

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        // Adds or refreshes rows in the DataSet to match those in the data source
        try
        {
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            sqlConnection.Close(dataTable );
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
            //Console.WriteLine(_Exception.Message);
            return null;
        }

        return dataTable;
    }


    public static void SendAutomatedEmail(DataTable dt, string recipient = "user@domain.com")
    {
        try
        {
            string mailServer = "server.com";

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
                                                   "it@domain.com",
                                                   recipient,
                                                   "Test Email",
                                                   dt.ToString()
                                                   );
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
            var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
            client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Does the table have to be in the body of the email?

Comment: yes, the content of email is the table

Comment: You can just write out the raw html for building a table, and put it in the email body, e.g.: <table><tr><th>header</th></tr><tr><td>row data</td></tr></table>. Note though, a lot of email clients have HTML-enabled mail turned off, so make sure you don't break the user experience.

Comment: remember to set message.IsBodyHTML=true.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ok, try this now:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataSet dataSet = getDataSet();
    string htmlString= getHtml(dataSet);
    SendAutomatedEmail(htmlString, "email@domain.com");
}

public static DataSet getDataSet(string CommandText)
{
    string cnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection2"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cnString);

    string CommandText = "select * from dbo.fs010100 (nolock)";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand =  new SqlCommand( CommandText, sqlConnection);

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    try
    {

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "header");
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception _Exception)
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();

        return null;
    }

    return dataSet;

}


public static string getHtml(DataSet dataSet)
{
    try
    {
         string messageBody = "<font>The following are the records: </font><br><br>";

         if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
             return messageBody;
         string htmlTableStart = "<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" >";
         string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
         string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style =\"background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;\">";
         string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
         string htmlTrStart = "<tr style =\"color:#555555;\">";
         string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
         string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\" border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px;\">";
         string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";

         messageBody+= htmlTableStart;
         messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;
         messageBody += htmlTdStart + "Column1 " + htmlTdEnd;
         messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

         foreach (DataRow Row in notShippedDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
         {
             messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrStart;
             messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + Row["fieldName"] + htmlTdEnd;
             messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrEnd;
         }
         messageBody = messageBody + htmlTableEnd;


         return messageBody;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          return null;
     }
 }

public static void SendAutomatedEmail(string htmlString, string recipient = "user@domain.com")

{
 try
 {
     string mailServer = "server.com";

     MailMessage message = new MailMessage("it@domain.com", recipient);
     message .IsBodyHtml = true;
     message .Body = htmlString;
     message .Subject = "Test Email";

     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
     var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
     client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
     client.Send(message);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {

 }

}
```

Comment: where does this loop the columns? Is this a table with just one column?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've made an object EmailGrid.cs which inherits from GridView.
Then used a method like below to render the HTML into a string.

```
  public string RenderControl()
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
            HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: i am doing this in console application, do not have system.web.dll dere

Comment: are you sending email via console app or web app either way you can add to the using at the top of the code using System.Web.Mail;

Comment: but i am not able to find referrence to system.web dll

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do the same thing but loop thru the datatable via a DataAdapter look at this link for a quick example .. because you are pretty much doing the same thing this example shows with the exception you are trying to pass the entire datatable vs building the results into the email body..
[How to use DataAdapter to DataTable via Email](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/6687441d-c97e-4083-9f6d-3948a5deee0d)

Answer (score 0):

Other dynamic function:

```
private string RenderDataTableToHtml(DataTable dtInfo)
    {
        StringBuilder tableStr = new StringBuilder();

        if(dtInfo.Rows != null && dtInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int columnsQty = dtInfo.Columns.Count;
            int rowsQty = dtInfo.Rows.Count;

            tableStr.Append("<TABLE BORDER=\"1\">");
            tableStr.Append("<TR>");
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsQty; j++)
            {
                tableStr.Append("<TH>" + dtInfo.Columns[j].ColumnName + "</TH>");
            }
            tableStr.Append("</TR>");

            for (int i = 0; i < rowsQty; i++)
            {
                tableStr.Append("<TR>");
                for (int k = 0; k < columnsQty; k++)
                {
                    tableStr.Append("<TD>");
                    tableStr.Append(dtInfo.Rows[i][k].ToString());
                    tableStr.Append("</TD>");
                }
                tableStr.Append("</TR>");
            }

            tableStr.Append("</TABLE>");
        }            

        return tableStr.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert in the Body message this code:

```
public string GetHtmlTable(string title, DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {
                string messageBody = "<font> "+title+" </font><br><br>";

                if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
                    return messageBody;
                string htmlTableStart = "<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" >";
                string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
                string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style =\"background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;\">";
                string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTrStart = "<tr style =\"color:#555555;\">";
                string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\" border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px;\">";
                string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";

                messageBody += htmlTableStart;

                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;
                
                foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    messageBody += htmlTdStart + column + htmlTdEnd;

                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    messageBody +=  htmlTrStart;


                    foreach (string item in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        messageBody += htmlTdStart;
                        messageBody += item;
                        messageBody += htmlTdEnd;
                    }
                    messageBody += htmlTrEnd;
                }
                messageBody += htmlTableEnd;


                return messageBody;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```